# How to rename a directory that has a special character in its name?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory named `.training&samples` into VertexAI (GoogleCloudPlatform).

I expect to rename it to `samples`

I tried `mv <path>/.training&samples <path>/samples`

I had:

```
bash: samples: command not found
(base) jupyter@karina:~/<path>$ mv: missing destination file operand after '<path>/.training'
```

If anyone has a solution for this problem, I'm more than grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape `&` with `\` (or put it inside of quotes):

```
mv <path>/.training\&samples <path>/samples
```

Comment: In bash, you can type in part of the path and then hit the Tab key -- it'll autofill as much as it can based on what directories and files actually exist, and it'll add appropriate escapes for funny characters like `&`.

Comment: neither `/` nor `"&"` worked. It gave the same answer for both `: No such file or directory`.  It ignores the name of the directory since `&` and only `.training` is recognised as a directory.

Comment: The escape character is not `/` (slash) but `\ ` (backslash). I don't know what you do but in my configuration both `.training\&samples` and `.training"&"samples` are working.

Comment: Sorry, Pierre. I wrote `/ `here, but used the `\ `  (backslash) at the code. It didn't worked here.